# Spnego / Kerberos support with hessian

Tags: java, kerberos, hessian, spnego

I crawled google a lot to find some documentation on the subject but did not find anything.
I am trying to use a kerberos ticket to access a secured server but i get a 401 error.

What i do is add a header with the base64 encoded token before calling the web service

```
HessianConnection conn = ...    
conn.addHeader("Authorization", "Negotiate " + token);
...
conn.sendRequest();
```

I know that hessian supports Basic auth (HessianProxyFactory => setUser/PWD/BasicAuth), but i m not sure about Spnego/Negotiate.

Note that we managed to setup spnego with cxf in another project (It has HttpAuthSupplierImpl), but this one uses hessian.

Question : is it possible or i am wasting my time ?
Thanks

Comment: If there is no built-in support, you have to patch it or provide the token yourself like in your demo code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i checked HTTP traffic server side with wireshark, it seems that headers are correctly sent with this code. So this works and this question can be closed. The ticket is however not correctly recognized but this is another problem ...